# What was the bus width of the 160-pin SO-RIMM?

Tags: memory

I know that the earlier RIMMs worked over a 16-bit bus and that they eventually moved to a 32-bit bus with the 232-pin package, but what was the bit-width of the 160-pin SO-RIMM?